# Kafka Compacted Topic , republish a deleted key

Tags: apache-kafka

Trying to wrap my head around the semantics of kafkas compacted topic, and a specific question is what happens when I republish a key that has previously been deleted:

1. "a" -> "value"
2. "a" -> null
3. "a" -> "new value"

Where (3) might happen soon after (2), i.e. before the delete tombstone has been cleaned out.

What I am hoping for is that (3) will be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compaction means kafka will eventually keep only the last value for a specific key. 
It is not a hard requirement as compaction is not real time, but in batch mode launched from time to time (you can configure the delay).
In compaction mode, Kafka will never delete all value of a key.

Setting a value `null` to a key act like others value. Kafka will sometime after remove previous key/value, but will keep this `null` value as long as there is no new value pushed.

If you set two value shortly one after the other, both value will remain in kafka until the next clean.

It is not a problem as the value will be stored in the same partition (well, if you work correctly with them) so that when you read the topic, the values will be read in same order as they are are stored.

Comment: OK, so what you are saying is that eventually only "a" -> "new value" will be in the log.

Comment: It will be in the log yes. As soon as you set the value and until a newer value is set.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, **(3)** will be kept as the last message.

Log compaction ensures that the last message produced for any given key will be kept in the topic's log. Log compaction also doesn't change the order of records.

Producing a record with value as `null` and a key, *(i.e: a tombstone record)*, will result in that record being kept on the log for as long as `delete.retention.ms` is specified as (it's a topic config, defaults to 1 day). Other messages older than the tombstone might be deleted because of compaction, but the tombstone will be kept for as long as that configuration says. But since compaction doesn't alter the order of records, the last message should still be **(3)**.